# How to change envPrefix in vite react?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, prefix, vite

I created a simple react app using `npm init vite Appname -- --template react` command.
And in `.env` file, variables have to have `VITE_` prefix, and don't look good.
I checked [this guide](https://vitejs.dev/config/index.html#envprefix), but don't know how to change the **envPrefix**.
Can someone tell me how to change envDir and envPrefix?

Thank you in advance for many help.

This is my `vite.config.js` file.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

Comment: Share your vite configuration file and how you tried setting this configuration setting in that file.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky, I added my `vite.config.js` file. I don't know how to, so I cannot edit file.

Comment: Okay great start. You shared the guide that shows the property you need to add to override that setting. Why haven’t you put that into the configuration file with your custom value? You are like 90% of that way there, just put that property into the file per the document that you shared.

Comment: I want to change **envDir** to `environment` folder and **envPrefix** to `CH_`. But don't know how to. Can you tell me how to?

Comment: Add those properties you referenced to the config file. Try adding this properties, see if results in the expected change. If not put the updated file into the question. `envPrefix: 'CH_'` for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try updating the file to include the properties that you shared the docs for:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  envPrefix: 'CH_',
  envDir: './environment'
})
```